# Работа с видео с помощью FFMpeg Android

Tags: php, java, android, ffmpeg

Всем привет!

Сейчас изучаю вопрос работы с видео на андройде. Изменение, воспроизведение, загрузку и т.д.
Как я понял, самая популярная библиотека для работы с видео - это FFMpeg.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы видео загружалось с сервера и показывалось пользователю. Пользователь мог бы изменять видео (склеивать с другими, добавлять водяные знаки и т.п.) и отправлять обратно на сервер.

Можно ли сделать такое с помощью FFMpeg? Как будет правильнее, скачивать видео с сервера на телефон пользователя, изменять его на клиенте и потом отправлять на сервер или отправлять видео пользователя на сервер и уже на нём изменять? А клиент использовать только для отображения результата.

Comment: Возможности Андроида будет недостаточно для полноценной работы с видео-потоками, поэтому лучше использовать сервер для этого. Опять же, тут многое зависит от функционала и длин видео.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ли сделать такое с помощью FFMpeg? - можно: режет, клеит, миксует. Но посмотри ещё gstreamer и vlc.

и уже на нём изменять? - да, изменять лучше на сервере, если мощностей сервера достаточно. По rtp передаете клиенту тольку ту часть которую он смотрит. Скачивать-изменять-закачивать слишком долго.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться.